# Вставка картинок в комментарии WP

Tags: wordpress

Есть комментарии, где есть кнопка, в которой можно добавить картинку. Сделана через `<input type='file>`. Но куда потом эта картинка отправляется после нажатия на кнопку, неизвестно:( А так же как вывести потом эту картинку в комментарии я тоже не знаю (Какой нужен код PHP?).

Суть вопроса:

1. Куда отправляются картинки, которые отправляются через `<input type='file>`
2. Как вставить картинку в комментарии (Какой нужен код PHP?)

Comment: Это должно быть известно тому, кто сделал эту кнопку. А ты не морочь голову и используй готовые плагины, позволяющие вставлять картинки в комменты.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, тогда плагины, ибо я нашел 2 плагина, но они уже очень старые (5 лет назад обновление их было)  и с помощью их не могу вставить

Comment: Учись пользоваться репо https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/comments+image/,  https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/comments+form/  и тп запросы для поиска.

Comment: Пробовал Comment Image, он как-то странно работает, даже плохо. И последнее обновление было 2 года назад

Comment: Зачем мне эта информация? К тому же ХЗ куда ты смотришь https://i.imgur.com/zW3A0sS.jpeg